# Jupyter Notebook:Pyhon3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I have edited my question by uploading the whole code, so if you could check this out @Nathon_Marotte Sir.
I am trying to run this code and it gives me an error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
observations = 1000
xs = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=(observations,1))
zs = np.random.uniform(-10,10,(observations,1))

inputs = np.column_stack((xs,zs))
print(inputs.shape)
noise= np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (observations, 1))
targets = 2*xs - 3*zs + 5 + noise
print(targets.shape)

#observations=1000
targets = targets.reshape(observations,)
fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

ax.plot(xs, zs, targets)

ax.set_xlabel('xs')
ax.set_ylabel('zs')
ax.set_zlabel('Targets')
ax.view_init(azim=250)
plt.show()
targets=targets.reshape(observations,)
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-28d2a78b4ad5> in <module>
      3 ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
      4 
----> 5 ax.plot(xs, zs, targets)
      6 
      7 ax.set_xlabel('xs')

F:\Softwares\Anaconda\Installed\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py in plot(self, xs, ys, zdir, *args, **kwargs)
   1467 
   1468         # Match length
-> 1469         zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, np.shape(xs))
   1470 
   1471         lines = super().plot(xs, ys, *args, **kwargs)

<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_to(*args, **kwargs)

F:\Softwares\Anaconda\Installed\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in broadcast_to(array, shape, subok)
    178            [1, 2, 3]])
    179     """
--> 180     return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)
    181 
    182 

F:\Softwares\Anaconda\Installed\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok, readonly)
    121                          'negative')
    122     extras = []
--> 123     it = np.nditer(
    124         (array,), flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok', 'zerosize_ok'] + extras,
    125         op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (1000,) and requested shape (1000,1)
```

As I am a newbie and not have sufficient knowledge to fix this. So if you could help me out to fix this bug out? That would be great.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Could you also please provide what the `targets` variable is ? Thank you

Comment: @NathanMarotte, yes sir.

Comment: targets = targets.reshape(observations,)
fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

ax.plot(xs, zs, targets)

ax.set_xlabel('xs')
ax.set_ylabel('zs')
ax.set_zlabel('Targets')
ax.view_init(azim=250)
plt.show()
targets=targets.reshape(observations,)

Comment: yes but in your code, you use `targets.reshape(observations,)` so I need to know what `targets` is **before** the code you sent

Comment: Here targets variable is actually i created some noise

Comment: noise= np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (observations, 1))
targets = 2*xs - 3*zs + 5 + noise

Comment: So the targets variable has assigned some value given above there. where(xs,zs, and noise) are the inputs

Answer (score 0):

I am done with my question and it worked when I used Google Colab resources.
Thank you all and especially @NathanMarotte